# Ajax Request doesnt work on my production env

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I found a while ago a snippet to post my form stuff via ajax to my PHP file.
On my development machine everything is working well, but when I moved to my production webspace I've got a problem with the ajax request status.
The Request will be sent and the complete form is disabled but it will never jump to fail, done or always.

I tried to upgrade the jquery version, also I have checked if there is an error with the file itself but the request tell me, that it is posted on the right file located on my webspace.

**Here is the snippet**

```
// Variable to hold request
var request;

// Bind to the submit event of our form
$("#form").submit(function (event) {

    // Prevent default posting of form - put here to work in case of errors
    event.preventDefault();

    // Abort any pending request
    if (request) {
        request.abort();
    }
    // setup some local variables
    var $form = $(this);

    // Let's select and cache all the fields
    var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");

    // Serialize the data in the form
    var serializedData = $form.serialize();

    // Let's disable the inputs for the duration of the Ajax request.
    // Note: we disable elements AFTER the form data has been serialized.
    // Disabled form elements will not be serialized.
    $inputs.prop("disabled", true);      

    // Fire off the request to /form.php
    request = $.ajax({
        url:  "postFile.php",
        type: "post",
        data: serializedData
    });

    // Callback handler that will be called on success
    request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        // Log a message to the console
        console.log("done");
    });

    // Callback handler that will be called on failure
    request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // Log the error to the console
        console.error(
            "The following error occurred: " +
            textStatus, errorThrown
        );
    });

    // Callback handler that will be called regardless
    // if the request failed or succeeded
    request.always(function () {
        // Reenable the inputs
        $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
    });

});
```

Comment: Can you use full url with http, domain etc in `url:  "postFile.php",` ?

Comment: Also look in the console log. For example if the page is https and you make an http request you may get errors

Comment: Check the path of server script where Ajax does request. You can do it in Network section in Chrome.

Comment: @IvanBolnikh Used the full domain with http://... doesnt work

Comment: @mplungjan Console don't tell me anything, page is http

Comment: @OPV https://imgur.com/a/tdkGU

Comment: Show please headers  and body HTTP

Comment: that is not your console. That is your Network. Please click the CONSOLE tab - also your jQuery seems to be pending rather than loaded

Comment: @OPV https://imgur.com/a/e5gU8 newsletter.php = postFile.php

Comment: @mplungjan after a while it jumps into the fail function and also print out this: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING